# How to find a web application folder based on url? Tomcat or JBoss

Tags: linux, tomcat, jboss

I have an URL of a application running like "server":8080/"application". I know that the server is JBoss or Tomcat. I have the access to the server(linux) and I would like to copy this application to other server, so I have to find the .war or .ear file to migrate. I tried running some "find" commands to search about the extension or something based on the name but I can´t find it. Is there a way to discover the folder based only in the url that is used to access? Regards,

Comment: Not easily, you don't even know which application server is in use. But there is the command [`lsof`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html) which will show you open files (and the server **must** have the application files open somewhere).

Comment: Try with `ps -axu | grep java` to locate the command used to run the server. Hopefully this would show you where the server is installed.